# Enable Environment Hub

Tags: managed-package

I want to enable Environment Hub in the DE org that contains a managed package. Will this cause any issue when try to upload a new package version or push an upgrade. Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Environment hub can be enabled in org which contains namespace but you shouldn't do if you are an ISV.
Hub creates some objects in the organisation and they can be modified as you want. If in any case your package make some dependency with those object then you won't be able to upload or push upgrade to customers because of dependencies.

A single bad configuration will ruin your org packaging capability and you will not have much option because environment hub once enabled then can not be disabled.

It is part of **best practice**, keeping your packaging code separate from any customization not related to managed package.

Also, Salesforce may refuse to enable Environment hub if they find managed package in that org.

Comment: Thanks Ashwani for letting me know on this.But I already did some research on that. My question is - Can we created Dev/Test/Demo Environments that are stipulated using environment hub. We need to create some discipline of our Managed package code in developer environment. At present we have one Dev Environment that contains this managed package code and also some further development is going on this org. And salesforce setup the environment hub for this development org. So I am surprised and bit confused on this.

Comment: @AishwaryaKumar In that case you have no option. You will have to take care that you don't make any dependency to environment hub application.  You can continue using that environment hub for you further development. It doesn't create extra components if you create any demo/Test/dev org. using that. Also verify that package doesn't have any dependency to the Env hub.

Comment: We got the Environment Hub enabled in the enterprise org. Now we have to connect our packaging dev org with the Environment Hub. Our managed code is there in this packaging dev org. Now we want to continue the development in the separate new dev org. Also want to have the security review at the same time for the already developed code that is on the packaging dev.

Comment: In the packaging org my domain is already setup. So can you suggest on the Points - Is it possible to connect the packaging org to the Environment Hub?If yes then how we can manage/continue the development in the new org that will be created from the Environment Hub. Pls Suggest

Comment: Can you please suggest on the above points.....